# How to implement data-list via mat-select of angular-material?

Tags: angular-material

Here is the code of an original dataList (select which has an option of customed typing):

```
<input type="text" list="selectCity" placeholder="select city" />
<data-list id="selectCity">
    <option [value]="New York" />
    <option [value]="London" />
    <option [value]="Paris" />
    <option [value]="Beijing" />
    <option [value]="Montreal" />
</data-list>
```

I want to create something like this via `<mat-select>` .
I saw few questions about it, but the answers were something like- "you can make another input that accepts the customed value..",
but in my app I want to **help** the user **to get** the city **easily** among a **very long list** of cities. so that solution cannot help me.
I tried something with `<mat-form-field>` and `<input>` but that made some problems...
Can you give me any effective solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>select city</mat-label>
      <mat-select>
        <mat-option value="option">New York</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option">London</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="option">Paris</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In this example, you can type a letter, and reach to the first option that starts with that letter.
It will be helpful in case the options are sorted in **alphabetical order**.
Else, see here: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples